# Flutter - The Xcode project defines schemes: Flutter Assemble, Runner

Tags: swift, flutter, macos, dart

While running from android studio, I am facing this error.

```
Launching lib/main_staging.dart on macOS in debug mode...
Running pod install...

The Xcode project defines schemes: Flutter Assemble, Runner
Exception: You must specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.
```

What is the proper way to run the app on MacOS?

Comment: May be mutliple flavour defined in your app, If you don't know what application flavor is follow this link https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b , You can use Xcode or visual studio code for selecting required flavour to run. An easy, temporary and immediate way is to create main.dart file inside lib folder with the databse configuration you want.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64088

Answer (score 5):

Add the exact xcode scheme name to your Build flavor in your edit configuration, as shown below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error while trying to run a flutter macos app. Creating a build scheme which matches the flavor name, like instructed in another answer, resulted in a different error:

`Exception: Unable to find expected configuration in Xcode project.`

I was finally able to run the flutter app by opening `macos/Runner.xcworkspace` in xcode and running the app there.